# Erro 1062 em alguns momentos no sistema de banco de dados

Tags: codeigniter, session

Estou enfrentando o seguinte erro ao executar meu app:

**Error Number: 1062
Duplicate entry '1484918130' for key 'PRIMARY'
INSERT INTO `sistema_session` (`id`, `ip_address`, `timestamp`, `data`) VALUES ('5bb80caf2df687b3d36def267b95400f82e209b1', '200.103.171.165', 1484918130, '__ci_last_regenerate|i:1484918130;identity|s:19:\"jeronimo@app.com.br\";email|s:19:\"jeronimo@app.com.br\";user_id|s:2:\"24\";old_last_login|s:10:\"1484917031\";username|s:8:\"Jeronimo\";id_empresa|s:2:\"14\";tipoMenu|s:1:\"1\";')
Filename: libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php
Line Number: 233**

Estou utilizando Codeigniter, Session do CI e estou utilizando o IonAuth.

Tenho outros sistemas utilizando a mesma estrutura e não apresenta esse erro.

Alguém já passou por isso?

Comment: Sua falha não é na `session`, é no banco. O `timestamp` é a chave primária, não pode ser repetido. Que banco é esse?

Comment: Estou utilizando mySql

Comment: Se tem uma função criando esses dados pra inserir no banco, é melhor mostrar. O erro indica que vc está tentando passar valores repetidos para uma chave primária do banco.

Comment: Mais como posso resolver isso porque não mudei nada na library ionauth

Comment: Se a biblioteca é que está gerando esses dados com essa falha, então vc tem duas opções: ou estuda mais profundamente a documentação e descobre um meio de evitar que isso ocorra, ou abandona o uso dessa biblioteca. Particularmente, nunca achei ninguém reclamando disso, inclusive, tem muito material ensinando a usar ([veja](http://www.universidadecodeigniter.com.br/autenticacao-com-ion-auth/)).

Comment: Eu utilizo a mesma biblioteca em outro servidor e funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Um palpite: a biblioteca parece utilizar timestamp pra gerar as chaves. O fato é que os timestams gerados estão se repetindo de vez em quando. Isso é sintoma de **hora errada no servidor**. Entenda: se o servidor não tem uma configuração que ajusta o horário, ele pode estar passando timestamp errado para a biblioteca, e ela está repetindo o timestamp e tentando gravar no banco, o que retorna seu erro.

Comment: Procure sincronizar o relógio do seu servidor e deixar a data sempre correta pra evitar essas coisas ([NTP](http://ntp.br/) ajuda). Um outro conselho seria definir o `Default timezone` do PHP (o que pode ser feito com `date_default_timezone_set()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema baixando um versão mais atual do plugins.